# Lodash filter and functional composition

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js, lodash

I have an array of objects with a `media` key and the value that may or may be not empty. I have a function to pick that key value and a function that checks that the value is empty so that `mediaEmptyComparer({media: ''})` returns true and `mediaEmptyComparer({media: 'somevalue'})` is false.

```
    var array = _.times(100, function () { return {media: Math.random() < 0.5 ? '' : 'value'} });

    var mediaPicker        = _.partialRight(_.get, 'media');
    var mediaEmptyComparer = _.flow(mediaPicker, _.isEmpty);

    var splittedArray = _.filter(array, mediaEmptyComparer);
    console.log(splittedArray);
```

When I try to use such function as the predicate for _.filter, it always fails (as in the example) but if I write:

```
    var splittedArray = _.filter(array, function (x) { return mediaEmptyComparer(x);});
```

it works. It's like if the value for each iteration is not passed as argument to the function. Any help? Thanks

Comment: Interesting ! Looking at it, remembering why I use es6 now :) ( `myArray.filter(a => a.media.length)`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Predicate of _.filter() method is invoked with three arguments: value, index|key and collection.
Use an _.ary() method to cap the number of arguments accepted by a method.
https://lodash.com/docs#ary

```
var splittedArray = _.filter(array, _.ary(mediaEmptyComparer, 1));
```

For more information check this:
https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/844

Good luck!

Comment: @Pandaiolo Thanks for the fiddle, mate! :)